# problems with fwrite/ file IO

Tags: c

for some reason fwrite does not work properly . can please someone help me to understand why ?

```
void insertBySize(int objectSize, unsigned char* buffer, int*kamaNish, unsigned char ch, FILE* fp)
//function that compress and writes to file charecters by their destined size.
{
    unsigned char leftOvers = 0;//a second buffer that will contain bits in case we need to write just part of byte to buffer.
    unsigned int counterLeftOver;// will tell us how many bits we keep aside.
    unsigned char mask;//mask that will help us to keep the left bits and put them aside.
    if (objectSize >= *kamaNish)//if the size of the object is bigger or equal to the number bits that remain to put in buffer.
    {
        counterLeftOver = objectSize - *kamaNish;// tell us how many bits we keep aside.
        mask = createBottomBitsLitMask(counterLeftOver);//creates mask with "counterLeftOver" bottom bits lit up.
        leftOvers = (mask&ch) << SIZE_OF_BYTE - counterLeftOver;//puts the remain bits in leftOver adjacent to the left.
        ch = ch >> counterLeftOver;//"drop" the saved bits.
        *buffer |= ch;//filling the buffer to full capacity.
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fp);//write the buffer to file.  /////DOES NOT WORK!!!!
        *buffer = leftOvers;//puts the remains of the previous char in buffer.
        *kamaNish = SIZE_OF_BYTE - counterLeftOver;//update the number bits that remain to put in buffer.
    }
    else
    {
        ch = ch << ((*kamaNish) - objectSize);//puts the leading bit "under" the first place for insertion to buffer.
        *buffer |= ch;//insert it.
        *kamaNish = *kamaNish - objectSize;////update the number bits that remain to put in buffer.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what “does not work properly” means here. What does it do? What should it do?

Comment: I get this error:      Unhandled exception at 0x77A56015 (ntdll.dll) in ProjectSummer2019.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000027.

Comment: Does it crash if you comment out the call to `fwrite`? If not, I suspect that `fp` is a null pointer returned by `fopen` due to an error opening the file.

Comment: we have a function called checkFile that checks if the file opened succsesfully . Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: Debug line by line and check the variables and see exactly where it crashes and why first

Comment: How do you open `fp` and call the function `insertBySize`?